# even and odd numbers while loop in php

Tags: php, while-loop

I want to make even and odd numbers via while loop like this

```
these are even 2,4,6,8,10
these are odd 1,3,5,7,9
```

I tried to make it with a for loop:

```
<?php

    $end=50;
    $even= "Even Numbers Are : ";
    $odd="<br /> Odd Numbers Are : ";

    for($i=1;$i<=$end;$i++)
    {
        if($i%2==0)
        {
            $even.=$i.",";
        }else $odd.=$i.","; 
    }   
    echo $even.$odd;

?>
```

Comment: Which problem do you have in your code?

Comment: @kiks73 I guess he wants to use `while()` loop instead `for()`... Sounds like another homework...

Comment: Would I be right in thinking that you want to do this with a "While" loop and your code currently works correctly with a "For" loop?

Answer (score 4):

Bit late to the party but i'm nice and just had to write it anyway

```
<?php
             $i=0;
             while($i <= 10){
                 if($i % 2 == 0){
                     echo $i." - Even,  ";
                 }else{
                      echo $i." - Odd,  ";
                 }
                 $i++;
             }
   ?>
```

Also, in your `for` loop, you're not opening the `else` but you are closing it.

Answer (score 3):

This is how to initiate variable:

```
$i = 0;
```

This is how to increment variable + 1:

```
$i = $i + 1;

// or simply

$i++;
```

This is how `while()` loop works:

```
while([expression here is true]) {
   // do stuff
}
```

With this knowledge you can try do your homework by yourself.

Docs:

- http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php

Answer (score 0):

```
 class IsOdd
   {

   public function __construct($x) {
    if ($x % 2 != 0) {
     echo "this odd number";
    } else {
     echo "this even number";
    }

   }

   }

  $odd = new IsOdd(5);
//output
this even number
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
echo"Ashutosh Verma Branch_IT_9889313834";
echo"<br />";
echo "Even No between 1 to 30 are:--";
echo"<br />";
for ($x=1; $x<=30; $x++)
{
    if( $x%2==0)
    {
    echo $x.", ";
    }
}
echo "<br />";
echo "Odd No between 1 to 30 are:--";
echo"<br />";
for ($x=1; $x<=30; $x++)
{
    if( $x%2!=0)
    {
    echo $x.", ";
    }
}
?>
---------------------------------------OOTPUT-------------------------------------
Ashutosh Verma Branch_IT_9889313834
Even No between 1 to 30 are:--
2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 
Odd No between 1 to 30 are:--
1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29,
```